# Outlook AddOn How to get selected emails?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm making an outlook addon and I'm trying to find a way to see which emails are selected, then be able to work with them through a foreach (or whatever).  If this is not possible, is there a way to fetch all items in a folder and get access to that information easily?  After that I need to move those items to another folder.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Application.ActiveExplorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa219397.aspx) method to get the currently active *Explorer* window (= the thing that displays the list of mails). Then you can use the [Explorer.Selection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171941.aspx) property to obtain the list of selected e-mails.

To move the mails, use the [MailItem.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220127.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Attached is my code to get the selected email from outlook messages.
For the olitem feel free to modify as you need.

```
Sub ReplyMSG()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olReply As MailItem  ' Reply
    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        Set olReply = olItem.ReplyAll
        olReply.HTMLBody = "Reminder" & vbCrLf & olReply.HTMLBody
        olReply.Display
        'olReply.Send
    Next olItem
End Sub
```